# Removing unused categories in Series results in duplicated categories

Tags: python, pandas, categories, categorical-data

So we create a series **with a NaN value** in **pandas 0.17**

```
>>> s = pd.Series(["A", "B", pd.np.nan]).astype("category")
```

Then we remove unused categories which gives the following result:

```
>>> s.cat.remove_unused_categories()
0      A
1      B
2    NaN
dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [B, A, B]
```

I've looked into `remove_unused_categories` code and see that `cat._codes` returns `[ 0  1 -1]` for this data sample. It results in 3 categories instead of 2. Well, this function works vice versa for now: it adds unwanted categories.)

Comment: This seems definitely like a bug, can you report it at https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues ? `remove_unused_categories` seems not yet designed to be able to deal with `NaN`s.

Comment: @joris seems like this function thinks of -1 to be the last item in categories array. P.S. i've got an exception and debugged completely different part of my code for about an hour.)

Comment: Posted it here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11599

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a confirmed bug in version 0.17, and has been fixed in version 0.17.1

Original question should be marked as answered.